# Queue: boolean put() objects at the end of the queue

Tags: java, boolean, queue, nodes

I did code (1) in class a while ago, does this code mean that the object newObj will be placed in the beginning of the queue? If so, is (2) in a way that the object newObj be placed at the end with the rear pointer to point to the last node?

(1)

```
public boolean put(AnyClass newObj) {
    if (currNodes == maxNodes) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Node newNode = new Node(newObj);

        if (front == null) {
            front = newNode;
        } else {
            rear.next = newNode;
        }

        rear = newNode;
        currNodes++;

        return true;
    }
}
```

(2)

```
public boolean put(AnyClass newObj) {
    if (currNodes == maxNodes) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Node newNode = new Node(newObj);

        if (rear == null) {
            rear = newNode;
        } else {
            front.next = newNode;
        }


        front = newNode;
        currNodes++;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code places a new element to the end (rear) of the queue. However, the second code doesn't place a new element to the start (front) and it does a completely different thing because this is a single linked list and you don't have a pointer to the back.(I assume that the `next` pointers of your linked list are directed from front to rear).

If you draw the linked list on a paper and execute the code line by line, you will understand well.